# All Image/Fast Image in React Native app not working on iOS 14 beta and Xcode 12 beta

Tags: image, react-native, xcode12, ios14

I've upgraded my iPhone device to iOS 14 beta and Xcode 12 beta. Then all Image/Fast Image on my React Native project can not show (which work well on previous iOS 13 and Xcode 11.5).

Comment: It maybe cause by the build system or something wrong when bundle resource. My others app which run on release mode still show the image, but sometimes app crash when i try to open screen that have image.

Comment: Ohh okay, I am actually running on the simulator and none of the images are showing.

Comment: Don't know why but today I just build app again and the issue has gone, LOL...

Comment: @EmBeCoRau you probably updated Pods and it automatically upgraded `SDWebImage`

Answer (score 29):

This is a problem with react-native <= 0.63.1 and iOS 14

This issue is fixed and merged to react native latest version. But if you want to fix your project now or you are using under 0.63.2 versions, there is a solution. (Thanks to https://bityl.co/3ksz)

**FIRST SOLUTION : If you can update React Native**

Update react-native to v0.63.2 or superior

Its was fixed in this release : https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v0632

**SECOND SOLUTION : If you can't update React Native**

1. **OPEN THE FILE FROM :**

> node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m

2. **EDIT SOURCE**

> From
>
> ```
> #pragma mark - CALayerDelegate
>
> - (void)displayLayer:(CALayer *)layer
> {
>   if (_currentFrame) {
>     layer.contentsScale = self.animatedImageScale;
>     layer.contents = (__bridge id)_currentFrame.CGImage;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> To
>
> ```
> #pragma mark - CALayerDelegate
>
> - (void)displayLayer:(CALayer *)layer
> {
>   if (_currentFrame) {
>     layer.contentsScale = self.animatedImageScale;
>     layer.contents = (__bridge id)_currentFrame.CGImage;
>   } else {
>     [super displayLayer:layer];
>   }
> }
> ```

3. **MAKE PATCH**

> `npx patch-package react-native`

4. **MAKE PATCH FILES TRACKED FOR GIT**

> `git add patches/*`

5. **ADD PACKAGE SCRIPT FOR AUTO APPLYING PATCHES**

> package.json
>
> ```
> "scripts": {
>   ...
>   "postinstall": "patch-package",
> }
> ```

It will patch from all patch files whenever you install packages.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't see that file in my node_modules folder. 0.59.10 here.

Comment: Don't forget to install the patch-package library

Comment: you should add to postinstall `npx patch-package`

Answer (score 2):

Try using `react-native+0.63.0.patch` as suggested here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29279#issuecomment-657201709

```
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m b/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m
index 21f1a06..2444713 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m
+++ b/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m
@@ -272,6 +272,9 @@ - (void)displayDidRefresh:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
 
 - (void)displayLayer:(CALayer *)layer
 {
+  if (!_currentFrame) {
+    _currentFrame = self.image;
+  }
   if (_currentFrame) {
     layer.contentsScale = self.animatedImageScale;
     layer.contents = (__bridge id)_currentFrame.CGImage;
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native/scripts/.packager.env b/node_modules/react-native/scripts/.packager.env
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..361f5fb
--- /dev/null
+++ b/node_modules/react-native/scripts/.packager.env
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+export RCT_METRO_PORT=8081
```

To use the patch 
run `npm i -g patch-package` 
Make a new folder called patches 
Make a new file called react-native+0.63.0.patch inside that folder 
Add the source code above 
run `patch-package` on the root of the project

Answer (score 2):

Update to React Native 0.63.2. Fixed in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/b6ded7261544c703e82e8dbfa442dad4b201d428

Answer (score 1):

This is related to https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/issues/3040.
Simply update `SDWebImage` in your `Podfile` or remove `Podfile.lock` and re-install.

Answer (score 1):

if you are not running latest react-native version ( > 0.63.2) or not planning to upgrade to latest version of react-native. Then you can be your temp fix, try changing node_modules as below

[Xcode 12 fix for IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63949851/react-native-ios-not-showing-images-pods-issue/63962601#63962601)

Answer (score 1):

I am using React Native v0.60.6 with React Native Fast Image v8.1.5.

Upgrading SDWebImage with `pod update SDWebImage` worked for me.

More specifically, I went from SDWebImage v5.8.1 to v5.9.2.

Comment: I also needed to run "pod repo remove trunk" before pod update, which was written in one of the previous answers. Otherwise it was giving an error which I can't find right now :/

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 12 builds seems to have issue, to fix i go to

> node_modules > react-native > Libraries > Images >
> RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m

And search for **if (_currentFrame)**

add else block to the if block as seen below code

```
if (_currentFrame) {
    layer.contentsScale = self.animatedImageScale;
    layer.contents = (__bridge id)_currentFrame.CGImage;
  } else {
    [super displayLayer:layer];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend modifying `node_modules`. Following worked for me:

1. npm install --save react-native-fix-image
2. npx react-native-fix-image
3. rebuild project

Answer (score 1):

My version information is as follows,

```
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-fast-image": "^7.0.2"
```

This worked for the pictures I show using FastImage.

```
pod repo remove trunk
pod update SDWebImage
```

For using the Image component that comes with react-native, you need to modify the source code. In the file `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image/RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m`, modify the `- (void)displayLayer:(CALayer *)layer` method It can be as follows:

```objectivec
-(void)displayLayer:(CALayer *)layer
{
   if (_currentFrame) {
     layer.contentsScale = self.animatedImageScale;
     layer.contents = (__bridge id)_currentFrame.CGImage;
   } else {// Fix the bug that react-native 0.61.5 does not show pictures on xcode12
     [super displayLayer:layer];
   }
}
```

[Here is the discussion for FastImage in github](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image/issues/730)

[Here is the discussion for react-native in github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29990)

Answer (score 0):

**It can display the image after adding [super displayLayer:layer]; if _currentFrame is nil if I understand correctly, _currentFrame should be for animated image, so if it is still image, we can use the UIImage implementation to handle image rendering, not sure if it is a correct fix.**

//path

> node_modules > react-native > Libraries > Images >
> RCTUIImageViewAnimated.m

```
 if (_currentFrame) {
    layer.contentsScale = self.animatedImageScale;
    layer.contents = (__bridge id)_currentFrame.CGImage;
  } else {
    [super displayLayer:layer];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the previous answers worked for me.

I solved it by removing `ios/Pods` directory, then running `pod install`.

So:

1. `cd ios`
2. `rm -rf Pods`
3. `pod install`