# React Native - ImageBackground not showing Image on TvOS

Tags: react-native, tvos, imagebackground

I'm trying to get an image on my `tvOS` app. But it is not showing up.

My `URL` is `https` and I've used this same code in `Android TV` and it works like a charm and when I `console.log` url it's perfect as well.

Follow bellow the behavior:

[image]

The "pink" image is a `fast-image`. Ok, it works very well, but the "red background" is a `ImageBackground` and not loading the image. Both use the same image repository.

Follow bellow the code:

```
<ImageBackground
          source={{
            uri: getEnvProperties().BASEURL_IMAGES + banner?.imageBanner,
          }}
          onError={this.handleError}
          style={{ height: getScaledValue(350), width, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
          <LinearGradient
            start={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
            end={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
            colors={['rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)']}
            style={styles.linearGradient}>
              //other codes....
          </LinearGradient>
 </ImageBackground>
```

`onError` event doesn't catch any error.

Anyone knows what can I do to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could this be related to your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62612812/all-image-fast-image-in-react-native-app-not-working-on-ios-14-beta-and-xcode-12 ?

Comment: @SamuliHakoniemi thanks a lot. It solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved in a new version of `TvOS` package as follow: [GitHub TvOS Changelog](https://github.com/react-native-tvos/react-native-tvos/compare/v0.63.1-1...v0.63.1-2).